# Android material design drawer layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm curious how the drawer layout of the latest Gmail app is created, with the image at top with collapsible menu then a list view below?

I would like to add this to my app, but fairly new to Android. I've already got a drawer layout setup, which has a list view. Just would like to have a similar style to Gmail.

See here for an example of what I mean: [Like this](http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/material-design-2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for, this helped me out a lot.
Yeah my question probably wasn't clear enough, but new on here so sorry.

See here: [Material Menu Drawer](https://github.com/D4ddy-LiLd4rk/MaterialMenuDrawer)

Answer (score 0):

try starting your project using SherlockFragments and activities.It gives you the same capabilities fairly easily . Here is a nice little tutorial for it.
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/

Try this out .

Answer (score 0):

The new Android Design Support Library is what you are looking for. It was released at Google I/O 2015 and it contains the following components:

- Navigation drawer view
- Floating labels for editing text
- Floating action button
- Snack bar
- Tabs

You can find out more about the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). More details on how to implement the components in your app can be found [here](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32).